# The awsconfiguration.json is not updating

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-cognito, amazon-lex

I was following through the lex sample provided by [aws](https://github.com/hossambusiness/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/LexSample).

From what I understand, I will have to create an IAM user, which I did and gave administrator access and login into that on Amplify. After which I just need to follow through the guide and Amplify will settle all the stuff for me. But the files created by Amplify are all filled with placeholders as shown in below without the actual PoolID, etc. I tried to locate these resources in my AWS console, but I could not find them and obviously I couldn't substitute the values manually.

TL;DR

Where do I find and access the resources Amplify create on my AWS console?

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
    "Version": "0.1.0",
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "REPLACED_BY_CLI",
                "Region": "REPLACED_BY_CLI"
            }
        }
    },
    "Lex": {
        "REPLACED_BY_CLI": {
            "Name": "REPLACED_BY_CLI",
            "Alias": "REPLACED_BY_CLI",
            "Region": "REPLACED_BY_CLI"
        }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps any expert out there could point out to me what I don't know, which is the real problem here, aws is just too confusing, I don't even know what I don't know.